# Mobile splash page & disappearing text

Tags: android, mobile, responsive-design, galaxy

We are putting up a basic splash page while we are working on the actual site. The problem is that when looking at it on some mobile devices most of the text seems to go above the screen in portrait/vertical view. Everything shows up fine in landscape/horizontal view.

I don't know how it looks on iPhones but it works on my HTC and on an iPad.

The problem is being reported from a Samsung Galaxy S3 (2 people told me the same thing). When the user zooms in they can move the text around to see it. I have no negative margins in the CSS and really no means of finding out why this is happening.

Does anyone else have this problem and can anyone see why it would be happening?

The site is here: http://find-thespot.com/

HMTL:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Spot</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/skyliner.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/underworld.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

    <body> 
                <div class="container">
                <h3>Coming Soon</h3>
                <h1>THE SPOT</h1>
                <h2>LASER TAG & ARCADE </h2>
                <a href="mailto:info@find-thespot.com" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
                </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background: url(imgs/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #0e0904;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    color: #000000;
}

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:210px;
    }


    /* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */


    h1{ 
        font-size:150px;
        line-height:145px;
        font-family: 'UnderWorldRegular', serif;
        margin: 0;
        /*font-weight:bold;*/
        word-wrap:break-word;
        word-break: normal;
    }

    h2{ 
        font-size:62px;
        line-height:60px;
        font-family: 'UnderWorldRegular', serif;
        margin: 0 0 25px;
        /*font-weight:bold;*/
        word-wrap:break-word;
        word-break: normal;
    }

    h3{
        font-size: 80px;
        line-height:75px;
        font-family: 'SkylinerRegular', sans-serif;
        margin: 0 0 15px;   
        /*font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;*/
        /*font-weight:bold;*/
        /*letter-spacing:2px;*/
    }

    a{ 
        font-size: 25px; 
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: underline; 
    }


    a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }



    /*Mobile CSS */

    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        h1{ font-size: 90px; line-height:95px;}
        h2{font-size: 35px; line-height:38px;}
        h3{font-size: 60px; line-height:50px;}
        a{ font-size: 17px; line-height:16px; }
        .container {margin-top: 120px;}
    }


    @media (max-width: 1025px) {
        h1{ font-size: 70px; line-height:95px;}
        h2{font-size: 30px; line-height:38px;}
        h3{font-size: 35px; line-height:50px;}
        a{ font-size: 17px; line-height:16px; }
        .container {margin-top: 60px;}
        body {background-image: url(imgs/bg-mob.jpg) !important;
    }

    @media (max-width: 770px) {
        .container {margin-top: 60px;}
    }


    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        h1{ font-size: 75px; line-height:75px;}
        h2{ font-size: 30px; line-height:30px;}
        h3{font-size: 40px; line-height:40px;}
        .container {margin-top: 50px;}
        /*a{ font-size: 13px; line-height:13px; }*/
        }

        @media (max-width: 360px) {
        .container {margin-top: 20px; min-width:200px;}
        }
```

Comment: you are not giving enough information, you would need to post some code or set an example on jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry! I just updated, I thought I had at least put a link to the splash page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the viewport tag in the `<head>` is missing, add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

also add this to your css:

```
html {height:100%}
body {height:100%}
```

this should solve the problem